# Mongoose - how to fetch specific number and message ID

Tags: node.js, mongoose, discord, eris

I'm trying to make the bot basically edit the message of any specific case mentioned for example if i do `-case 5 test` it will look for case 5 and it's message. So far when i do it, it basically changes the recent case number message, instead of the one i want it to change. like if i do `case 5 test` and the latest case is #9, it will change 9 instead of 5.

This is how i send the message:

```
Modlog.findOneAndUpdate({ guildID: msg.channel.guild.id }, { $inc: { 'caseID': 1 } }, { new: true }, async function (err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!doc) return;
        if (doc.modLog.enabled) {
            if (msg.channel.guild.channels.get(doc.modLog.channelID)) {
                let m = await msg.channel.guild.channels.get(doc.modLog.channelID).createMessage({
                    embed: {
                        title: `${action} | Case #${doc.caseID}`,
                        color: colour,
                        fields: [
                            {
                                name: 'User',
                                value: user,
                                inline: true
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'Moderator',
                                value: moderator ? moderator : 'No issuer.',
                                inline: true
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'Reason',
                                value: reason ? reason : 'No reason.'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
                doc.messageID = m.id;
                doc.type = action;
                doc.caseID = doc.caseID;
                //doc.caseID = m.id
                doc.moderatorID = moderator,
                doc.targetID = user
                doc.save();
            }
        }
    })
```

that is how i send my message. And you can see i'm storing the things so when someone changes a specific case's reason, for example: `case 5 spamming`, i would want it to look for caseID 5, and then edit the message through it's  ID. but i'm not sure how am i doing it wrong. I'm trying to make each case store it's own message ID and i would really appreciate any help. This is what i use to look for the case and edit's reason.

````
Modlog.findOne({ guildID: msg.guildID }, async (err, doc) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!doc.modLog.enabled) return msg.channel.createMessage(`Modlog is not enabled in this server! ${this.emoji.cross}`);

        if (isNaN(Number(caseID))) return msg.channel.createMessage(`Case \`#${caseID}\` was not a number! ${this.emoji.cross}`);

        if (doc.caseID === undefined) return msg.channel.createMessage(`Couldn\'t find case \`#${caseID}\`! ${this.emoji.cross}`);

        const moderator = this.bot.users.get(doc.moderatorID) || {
            username: 'Unknown User',
            discriminator: '0000'
        }

        const target = this.bot.users.get(doc.targetID) || {
            username: 'Unknown User',
            discriminator: '0000'
        }

        let embed = {
            title: `${doc.type} | Case #${doc.caseID}`,
            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'User',
                    value: `${target.username}#${target.discriminator} (${target.id})`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'Moderator',
                    value: `${moderator.username}#${moderator.discriminator} (${moderator.id})`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'Reason',
                    value: reason
                }
            ]
        };

        try {
            await this.bot.editMessage(doc.modLog.channelID, doc.messageID, { embed: embed });
            await msg.channel.createMessage(`Case **#${caseID}** has been updated. ${this.emoji.tick}`);
        } catch (e) {
            await msg.channel.createMessage(`I\'m unable to edit that case or it has been deleted. ${this.emoji.cross}`);
        }
    });```
````

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Search for Case ID
It seems you didn't look for the case ID, and only looked for the guild's ID in the filter parameter.

```js
Modlog.findOneAndUpdate({ guildID: msg.channel.guild.id }, { ... }, { ... }, ... {
        ...
}
```

In your code, only `guildID` was passed into the filter parameter. This causes Mongoose to look for the most recently initialized document for the server. For your case, you should also pass `caseID` into the filter parameter.

```js
Modlog.findOneAndUpdate({ guildID: msg.channel.guild.id, caseID: caseIDArg }, { ... }, { ... }, ... {
        ...
}
```

Replace `caseIDArg` with your supposed caseID argument in the message's content. For example, `args[1]` or however you programmed your argument handler to work.

Hope this helped to answer your question!

Comment: should it not be findAndUpdate? since i'm not just looking for one?